# Grid view is not being shown correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Grid view is not being shown with space, rows and column wise and When I am clicking delete menu item, it is passing the last array value (last card's value) to the function, not the clicked card's value. Something is wrong in Grid view.

Following is the data used by the cards. Import statements are there.

Array:

```
    0: {id: "5", title: "Java", price: "78$"} 
    1: {id: "2", title: "C++", price: "79$"} 
    2: {id: "4", title: "C", price: "127$"} 
    3: {id: "1", title: ".Net", price: "65$"} 
    4: {id: "3", title: "React Js", price: "67$"}
```

This is the code of my component:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  card: {
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  actions: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
});

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 40;

class Products extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      searchString: ''
    };
    this.getProducts()
  }
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  delete = id => {
    alert(id)
    axios.post('http://localhost:9022/products/delete/' + id)
      .then(res => {
        let updatedProducts = [...this.state.products].filter(i => i.id !== id);
        this.setState({ products: updatedProducts });
      });
  }

  getProducts() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getAll')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ products: res.data });
        console.log(this.state.products);
      });
  }

  onSearchInputChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value) {
      this.setState({ searchString: event.target.value })
    } else {
      this.setState({ searchString: '' })
    }
    this.getProducts()
  }

  render() {
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField style={{ padding: 24 }}
          id="searchInput"
          placeholder="Search for products"
          margin="normal"
          onChange={this.onSearchInputChange} />
        <Grid container spacing={12}>
          <Grid item xs={4} xm={4}>
            <div className="row">
              {this.state.products.map(currentProduct => (
                <div key={currentProduct.id}>
                  <Card>
                    <CardHeader
                      action={
                        <IconButton aria-label="More"
                          aria-owns={open ? 'long-menu' : null}
                          aria-haspopup="true"
                          onClick={this.handleClick}>
                          <MoreVertIcon />
                          <Menu
                            id="long-menu"
                            anchorEl={anchorEl}
                            open={open}
                            onClose={this.handleClose}
                            PaperProps={{
                              style: {
                                maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
                                width: 100,
                              },
                            }}
                          >

                          <MenuItem component={Link} to={'/products/' + currentProduct.id}>Edit
                                 </MenuItem>

                          <MenuItem onClick={() => this.delete(currentProduct.id)}>Delete
                                 </MenuItem>

                          </Menu>
                        </IconButton>
                      }
                      title={currentProduct.title}
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                      <Typography component="p">
                        {currentProduct.id}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Products);
```

Comment: Please reformat the data you provided(i.e. your array you pass to the cards). And try provide specific details, as your post is mostly code!

Comment: By: When I am clicking delete menu item,it is passing last array value(last card's value) to the function not the clicked card's value. You mean this part `<MenuItem onClick={() => this.delete(currentProduct.id)}>Delete</MenuItem>`?

Comment: yes, its passing last card id.

Comment: You are mixing Material-UI library with what looks like Bootstrap? Why? No, just pick 1 UI library and stick to it.

Comment: material, i want to use.

Comment: I agree with @JackPilowsky with that. And I don't believe that it is always passing the last `id` of the last object of your array. Based on your code, and if the `this.state.products` structured as the `Array` you provided, it should return the respective id of each object!

Comment: It is passing the last card value.

Answer (score 0):

I see what the problem is. It's a problem with your code logic.

What you're trying to do in the `action` section of the `CardHeader` is rendering a `Menu` that has two static items in it

> `<MenuItem component={Link} to={'/products/' + currentProduct.id}>Edit</MenuItem> <MenuItem onClick={() => this.delete(currentProduct.id)}>Delete</MenuItem>`

The thing is the `Menu` has to have a unique id, but each time you render it you give the same => `simple-menu` instead you could do something like `simple-menu-${currentProduct.id}`. And the best to do is that you render a separate  component from the `CardHeader` instead of `actions`.

> This gives you more control over you component and each element you want to render.

See and edit it here:
[image: Edit MaterialUI Remove Product]

I personally don't like to put a `Menu` inside of that card, instead I'd put `icons` to the top left/right of the card.

> Uncomment the action property in the `CardHeader` and comment out the component one to see what I mean!

I hope that's clear, let me know if it isn't!

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you can fix which should solve all your problems, or at least guide you through the right direction.

I will guide you through, but it would be ideal if I you [read the docs first](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

1. You are calling `this.getProducts()` inside your constructor, and that function uses `setState`
2. You are initialising and setting `anchorEl` in the state outside of the constructor
3. You are calling `super` without passing on props, which might lead to bugs
4. You are not binding functions that use `this` (handleClick, handleClose, getProducts, etc), which could lead to `undefined` state of `this`.
5. You are calling functions that get values from the state right after calling `setState`, which might not get the correct values because of how `setState` works in React.

You should **avoid all**.

## **Constructor, bindings, first time fetch**

**Constructor**

[Constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) from the official docs:

> You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your
>   component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to
>   this.state directly in the constructor:
>
> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
>   When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.
>
> Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:
>
> - Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
> - Binding event handler methods to an instance.

Your code:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    products: [],
    searchString: ''
  };
  this.getProducts()
}
state = {
  anchorEl: null,
};
```

Change it to:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    products: [],
    searchString: '',
    anchorEl: null,
  };
  this.onSearchInputChange = this.onSearchInputChange .bind(this);
  this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
}
```

**First time fetch**

To call `this.getProducts()` when the app starts, don't use the constructor, use `componentDidMount` instead.

[componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) from the official docs:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Create this function inside the component:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.getProducts();
}
```

**Bindings**

[Binding](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance) from the official docs:

> There are several ways to make sure functions have access to component
>   attributes like this.props and this.state, depending on which syntax
>   and build steps you are using
>   - Bind in Constructor (ES2015)
>   - Class Properties (Stage 3 Proposal)
>   - Bind in Render

You can use any of these, but I suggest you use the first one.

Your functions:

```
handleClick = event => {
  this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
};

handleClose = () => {
  this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
};
```

Change them to:

```
handleClick(event) {
  this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
};

handleClose() {
  this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
};
```

## **setState**

**Correct use of setState**

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) from the official docs

> ```
> setState(updater[, callback])
> ```
>
> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user
>   interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.
>
> ```
> this.setState((state, props) => {
>   return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
> });
> ```

So you should not do this:

```
onSearchInputChange = (event) => {
  if (event.target.value) {
    this.setState({ searchString: event.target.value })
  } else {
    this.setState({ searchString: '' })
  }
  this.getProducts()
}
```

Because you cannot guarantee that when `this.getProducts()` is called, the previous `setState` functions have finished. This means that it might work most of the times, but there would be some cases when React hasn't finished updating the state and you are already calling `this.getProducts()`.

Instead, you should call `this.getProducts()` once setState has finished, and to guarantee that just use the callback like this (and I am also changing the function's declaration because we already bound it in the constructor with the previous change):

```
onSearchInputChange(event) {
  let newSearchString = '';
  if (event.target.value) {
    newSearchString = event.target.value;
  }

  // call getProducts once React has finished updating the state using the callback (second argument)
  this.setState({ searchString: newSearchString }, () => {
    this.getProducts();
  });
}
```

Your `getProducts` is OK (now that we bound it in the constructor), but you are calling `console.log` when it should not be called:

```
getProducts() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getAll')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ products: res.data });
      console.log(this.state.products);
    });
}
```

Based on the previous explanation of setState, call it like this:

```
getProducts() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:9022/products/getAll')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ products: res.data }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.products);
      });
    });
}
```

## **Your delete function**

Assuming that your data is in fact an array, like this:

```
products: [ 
  {id: "5", title: "Java", price: "78$"} 
  {id: "2", title: "C++", price: "79$"} 
  {id: "4", title: "C", price: "127$"} 
  {id: "1", title: ".Net", price: "65$"} 
  {id: "3", title: "React Js", price: "67$"}  
]
```

the code that you have should work with the previous changes in the component. But, there is something you can improve as well.

This is your code:

```
delete = id => {
  alert(id)
  axios.post('http://localhost:9022/products/delete/' + id)
    .then(res => {
      let updatedProducts = [...this.state.products].filter(i => i.id !== id);
      this.setState({ products: updatedProducts });
    });
}
```

I will refer back to the docs to the [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) documentation where the updater function is explained:

> ```
> setState(updater[, callback])
> ```
>
> The first argument is an updater function with the signature:
>
> ```
> (state, props) => stateChange
> ```
>
> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is
>   being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes
>   should be represented by building a new object based on the input from
>   state and props. For instance, suppose we wanted to increment a value
>   in state by props.step:
>
> ```
> this.setState((state, props) => {
>   return {counter: state.counter + props.step}; 
> });
> ```
>
> Both state and props received by the updater function
>   are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is
>   shallowly merged with state.

It's important to understand when to use this updater function, and the `state` param in that function.

The easiest case is the one they mention:

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step}; 
});
```

This could be done like this:

```
this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + this.props.step});
```

But since you **cannot guarantee** that `setState` has been successful and that it has finished updating the values, you should do it using the updater function.

**Now, back to your delete function.**

Change this:

```
delete = id => {
  alert(id)
  axios.post('http://localhost:9022/products/delete/' + id)
    .then(res => {
      let updatedProducts = [...this.state.products].filter(i => i.id !== id);
      this.setState({ products: updatedProducts });
    });
}
```

to this (notice that I changed the parameter name `state` to `prevState` in the updater function so that it makes more sense and it's easier to understand):

```
delete = id => {
  alert(id);
  axios.post('http://localhost:9022/products/delete/' + id)
    .then(res => {

      // To guarantee you get the correct values, get them from the state in the updater function in setState
      this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => { 
        // This happens inside the setState function
        let updatedProducts = [...prevState.products].filter(i => i.id !== id);

        // The updater function must return the values that will be modified in the state
        return ({
          products: updatedProducts 
        });
      });
    });
}
```

It's important to notice that filtering before setState like this:

```
let updatedProducts = [...this.state.products].filter(i => i.id !== id);
this.setState({ products: updatedProducts });
```

Will work most of the times but it is not recommended, use the updater function instead when handling this situations to ensure everything works every time.